# Is black in check?

Tags: checkmate, check

I know this sounds like a really basic question, but I couldn't find it anywhere on the site...  On the following board, is the black king actually in check (assuming it's his move)? My thoughts are just that white technically should not be allowed to move his bishop away, as it would place his king in check.

[image: Is black king in check?]

My *guess* would be that black *is* in check because white could take his king before black could take his, but I'm looking for confirmation / refutation...

I guess what really made me ask the question was when I was placed in a situation in a chess game where I was in a similar situation, but I was able to place the white king in checkmate; something like this:

[image: Checkmate by rook]

...where rook to a7 results in a checkmate for white.

Again, I have a feeling that the fact that white is in direct line to take black takes precedence over the rule that you are not allowed to put yourself in check by your moves, but again, I'm looking for confirmation / denial.  Thanks!

Comment: @konsolas nailed it.  Thanks, and sorry for duping. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, black is in check. Pinned pieces are able to give check.

In your second position, `Ra7#` is an illegal move. Black is in check, and thus must get out of check immediately.